# Module's dependencies aren't getting resolved and pom's symbol looks different

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-12

I can't seem to figure out why one of my Modules can't resolve dependencies.  Dependencies that appear in the pom still show up as red in the files. The only difference I've noticed between this module and a module whose dependency resolution works is this symbol. Can anyone tell me what the difference in symbols means and how to fix it?

Good pom.xml symbol

[image]

Bad pom.xml symbol

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a profile in the parent module that defines whether or not the Module in question should or should not be built.  Going over to the Maven Project tab on the right and activating the profile to build the Module in question told intellij to recognize the pom.xml as a "pom" and not just plain xml and now all the dependencies work.